# Kafka Streams Stateful Aggregation Rebalancing causing processing to pause on all partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Kafka broker version: 2.8.0
Kafka Streams client version: 2.6.2

I am running kafka streams stateful aggregations on K8s statefulset with persistent volume attached to each pod. I have also specified

props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_INSTANCE_ID_CONFIG, podName);

which makes sure it gets the sticky partition assignment.

Enabled standby replica -
props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STANDBY_REPLICAS_CONFIG, 1);

and set
props.put(StreamsConfig.ACCEPTABLE_RECOVERY_LAG_CONFIG, "0");

However, I'm seeing that when pods restart - it triggers rebalances and causes processing to be paused on all pods till the rebalance and state restore is in progress.

My understanding is that even if there is a rebalance - only the partitions that should be moved around will be restored in a cooperative way and not pause all the processing. Also, it should failover to standby replica in this case and avoid state restoring on other pods.

could someone please help if I'm missing something?

I have increased session timeout to 180 seconds and max poll interval to 15 mins to minimize rebalances.

Also added
props.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG,
CooperativeStickyAssignor.class.getName());

to enable CooperativeStickyAssignor